# Async await call does not return

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, akavache

I have a problem, where i call an async method, and the call does not return back. I assume its a race of threads. How do I write this correctly?

This is where it starts. I first call an async method called "GetCachedValuesAsync"

```
public void OnNavigatingTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await GetCachedValuesAsync();
            ClipRefernce = GenerateRefernce(clips);
        });
    }
```

Here is the method signature for GetCachedValueAsync

```
public async Task  GetCachedValuesAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            clips = await BlobCache.LocalMachine.GetObject<List<Clip>>("clips");
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException ex)
        {
            clips = new List<Clip>();
        }
    }
```

I do not get the call returned from BlobCache, BlobCahce method is part of a library called akavache.

The code also does not hit: `ClipRefernce = GenerateRefernce(clips);`

I appreciate your help

**Edit 1**

This is GenerateRefernce method.

```
public string  GenerateRefernce(List<Clip> clips)
    {
        string refernce = "";
        if(clips.Count > 0)
        {
            var clip = clips.LastOrDefault();
            refernce = String.Format("Ref {0:yyyy}/{1}",DateTime.Now , clip.ClipId + 1);
        }
        else{
            refernce = String.Format("Ref {0:yyyy}/{1}", DateTime.Now, 1);
        }
        return refernce;
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: @Amit : I dont get any exception

Comment: @Amit : I have made those changes. But that does not resolve the issues

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425210/akavaches-getobjectt-hangs-when-awaited-any-idea-what-is-wrong-here

Comment: Though the questions sounds exactly the same issue, i have tried both the solutions in the page, but does not work

Comment: I can't see any reason why the answer you've accepted would make any difference.

Comment: I've seen an issue like this before with the first call into Akavache because of how the BlobCache is initialized causing a deadlock. https://github.com/akavache/Akavache/issues/216.  Can you try installing the latest version 5 bits from myget and see if you have the same issue? Or install the alpha version 6 from nuget ?  Or try initializing Akavache early in your app startup and just make a dummy call to LocalCache like LocalCache.Insert("key", new object()).subscribe(). If none of that works try pausing the application and looking at the threads to see where it's deadlocked

Comment: I really did not get to resolve this issue. I ended up switching to sqlite with ef core2. Works great for my need now

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the sync method from the `Task.Run` like this:

```
public void OnNavigatingTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await GetCachedValuesAsync();
    });

    ClipRefernce = GenerateRefernce(clips);
}

public async Task  GetCachedValuesAsync()
{
    try
    {
        clips = await BlobCache.LocalMachine.GetObject<List<Clip>>("clips");
    }
    catch (KeyNotFoundException ex)
    {
        clips = new List<Clip>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Without any explanation, this isn't terribly helpful. Without knowing what `GenerateReference` does, I have no idea why this would help at all.

Comment: This smells of a lucky guess, unless you care to elaborate why this will help?

Comment: @JonSkeet , I have added the GenerateRefernce method